# Is there a self-correcting iterative method for approximating pi without using transcendental functions?

Tags: approximation, pi, applications, newton-raphson

The Newton-Raphson method is an iterative method for finding a root of a function, and it is self-correcting in the sense that any error in the initial input is reduced with each iteration so that it will still converge to the correct answer.

Is there a method to compute pi to higher and higher precision that has the same self-correcting property but also does not use transcendental functions? I have only been able to find methods that use transcendental functions, like applying Newton-Raphson to $x - \tan(x)$ or iterating the formula $x = x + \sin(x)$ over and over.

Comment: There are many infinite sums and infinite products for $\pi$ where the error is reduced each time you include a new term.

Comment: [Take your pick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Development_of_efficient_formulae).

Comment: @noumenon28 Do you consider the following quadratically convergent iteration based on the AGM (from Borwein & Borwein, *Pi and the AGM*, Wiley 1987) as an iteration of the desired type? On p. 46: $x_{0}:=\sqrt{2}$,
$\pi_{0}:=2+\sqrt{2}$, and 
$y_{1}:=2^{1/4}$. 
Define
$x_{n+1}:=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{x_{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_{n}}}\right)$,
$y_{n+1}:=\frac{y_{n}\sqrt{x_{n}}+1/\sqrt{x_{n}}}{y_{n}+1}$,
$\pi_{n}:=\pi_{n-1}\frac{x_{n}+1}{y_{n}+1}$. The $\pi_{n}$ converge monotonically to $\pi$.

Comment: If you make your question precise, then I think it would require pi to be an algebraic number and it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I was given this one
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+\sin (a_{n-1}) \qquad \text{with} \qquad a_0=3$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a_n \\
 0 & \color{red}{3.}0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
 1 & \color{red}{3.141}1200080598672221007448028081102798469332642523 \\     
 2 & \color{red}{3.1415926535}721955587348885681408797467429928172150 \\  
 3 & \color{red}{3.14159265358979323846264338327950}9759271524572210 \\    
 4 &\color{red}{ 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Note that the iteration of $x \mapsto x + \sin(x)$ is already mentioned in the question, and the author explicitly asks for methods which do “not use transcendental functions.”

Comment: I also doubt that the method is “self-correcting.” If some $a_n > \pi$ due to rounding errors, then the next itererates increase further towards $2\pi$.

Comment: @MartinR. I do not agree. Use Darboux theorem and you avoid all problems.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing except at the points $k \pi$, so any rounding error which leads to some $a_n > \pi$ will not be “corrected.” Perhaps it depends what “self-correcting” exactly means. – In any case, my first comment still applies.